# Try Editing my form to update a user details but form refuse to update in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to update a user details on a form. I have created a UpdateForm Component that runs componentDidMount to get a particular user and I also used static getDerivedStateFromProps to pre-populate the form with that user details. But when it comes to edit the form directly from the front end i am not able to edit the pre-populated form.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookie from 'cookies-js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import fetchSingleMasterAgent from
  '../../../actions/ownerActions/masterAgentsActions/fetchSingleMasterAgent';
import TextField from '../../common/TextField';
import UserInputValidation from '../../../middlewares/validateMasterAgentInput';

/**
 * @class UpdateMasterAgentForm
 */
class UpdateMasterAgentForm extends Component {
    state = {
      id: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.id : null,
      fullname: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.fullname : '',
      username: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.username : '',
      address: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.address : '',
      email: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.email : '',
      password: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.password : '',
      phoneNumber: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.phoneNumber : '',
      device1: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.device1 : '',
      device2: this.props.singleMasterAgent ? this.props.singleMasterAgent.device2 : '',
      errors: {}
    }

    /**
   *
   * @param {*} prevProps
   * @returns {*} - single master agent object
   */
    componentDidMount() {
      const phoneNumber = Cookie.get('number');
      const { fetchSingleMasterAgent } = this.props;
      fetchSingleMasterAgent(phoneNumber);
    }

    /**
   *
   * @param {*} nextProps
   * @returns {*} - single master agent object
   */
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      return {
        id: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.id,
        fullname: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.fullname,
        username: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.username,
        address: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.address,
        email: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.email,
        phoneNumber: `${nextProps.singleMasterAgent.phoneNumber}`,
        password: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.password,
        device1: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.device1,
        device2: nextProps.singleMasterAgent.device2,

      };
    }

    /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @returns {*} - state
   */
  onChange = (event) => {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    if (errors[event.target.name]) {
      const newErrors = Object.assign({}, errors);
      delete newErrors[event.target.name];
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        errors: newErrors
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
    }
  }
 
  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @returns {*} - state
   */
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // const { CreateMasterAgentRequest } = this.props;
    if (this.isValid()) {
      this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
    //   CreateMasterAgentRequest(this.state);
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @returns {*} - state
   */
 isValid = () => {
   const { errors, isValid } = UserInputValidation.masterAgentInputValidation(
     this.state
   );
   if (!isValid) {
     this.setState({ errors, password: '' });
   }

   return isValid;
 }

 /**
   *
   * @returns {*} - render
   */
 render() {
   const {
     phoneNumber,
     username,
     email,
     fullname,
     address,
     password,
     device1,
     device2,
     errors
   } = this.state;
   const updateMasterAgentForm = (
     <div className="row">
       <div className="col-xl-12">
         <section className="hk-sec-wrapper">
           <h5 className="hk-sec-title">Edit Form</h5>
           <p className="mb-25">Hello Owner kindly use the form below to update a given master agent of your choice.</p>
           <hr />
           <div className="row">
             <div className="col-sm">
               <form>
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="firstName">Fullname</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.fullname}
                       className="myfullname"
                       id="firstName"
                       placeholder="Enter Fullname"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="fullname"
                       value={fullname || ''}
                       type="text"
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="lastName">Username</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.username}
                       className="myusername"
                       id="lastName"
                       placeholder="Enter Username"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="username"
                       value={username || ''}
                       type="text"
                     />
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="firstName">Address</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.address}
                       className="myaddress"
                       id="address"
                       placeholder="Enter Address"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="address"
                       value={address || ''}
                       type="text"
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.email}
                       className="myemail"
                       id="email"
                       placeholder="you@example.com"
                       type="email"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="email"
                       value={email || ''}
                     />
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className=" col-md-6  form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.password}
                       className="mypassword"
                       id="password"
                       placeholder="Password"
                       type="password"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="password"
                       value={password || ''}
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="firstName">Phone Number</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.phoneNumber}
                       className="myphonenumber"
                       id="phoneNumber"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="phoneNumber"
                       value={phoneNumber || ''}
                     />
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className=" col-md-6  form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="email">POS Devices</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.device1}
                       className="mydevice1"
                       placeholder="Number of POS devices"
                       type="text"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="device1"
                       value={device1 || ''}
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <label htmlFor="firstName">IGR Devices</label>
                     <TextField
                       error={errors.device2}
                       className="mydevice2"
                       id="device2"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Number of IGR devices"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       field="device2"
                       value={device2 || ''}
                     />
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <hr />
                 <div className="text-center">
                   <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update Master Agent</button>
                 </div>
               </form>
             </div>
           </div>
         </section>
       </div>

     </div>
   );
   return <div>{updateMasterAgentForm}</div>;
 }
}

UpdateMasterAgentForm.propTypes = {
  singleMasterAgent: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  fetchSingleMasterAgent: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  singleMasterAgent: state.fetchSingleMasterAgent.singleMasterAgent,
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSingleMasterAgent })(UpdateMasterAgentForm);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, `getDerivedStateFromProps` always 'resets' your state to the agent you fetched. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops says that it is used on EVERY updates, not only when props change. So once you remove that, your issue is how to initialize your form values correctly.

```js
// from props
// remove state = and add a constructor
constructor(props) {
  const agent = props.agent
  this.state = {
    // get from lodash, less code
    id: get(agent, 'id', null),
    username: get(argent, 'username', ''),
    ... and on and on
  }
}
// from your request
init = (singleMasterAgent) => {
  // pick from 'lodash', or you can keep verbose native style
  this.setState(pick(singleMasterAgent, ['id', 'username', ... all your values]))
}
componentDidMount() {
  const phoneNumber = Cookie.get('number');
  const { fetchSingleMasterAgent } = this.props;
  fetchSingleMasterAgent()
  // add this line
    .then(this.init)
}
```

I would add that, given that you have no condition around your API call, you seem to be always be fetching the user, hence you would not need the 'props' initialization, so I would remove the constructor and add the initial state back, like so.

```js
state = { id: null, username: '', ... and everything.}
```

And if you only rely on the API call to populate your form values, you can remove `mapStateToProps` aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But componentDidMount is the method that handles the api call for a single agent and it is from there I get the values to populate the form. componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchAgent(phoneNumber).then(this.init);
}

Comment: I do not understand how it is a problem, I wasn't trying to prevent you from fetching data here. I updated my answer so you can pinpoint what to add in your `componentDidMount`.

Comment: How does getDerivedStateFromProps() always reset to the fetched data? I read the link but I don't see where that's mentioned.

Comment: @Fran It's not all `getDerivedStateFromProps`, it is this one in particular. If you look at the function, all the data come from `nextProps`. because the OP uses `setState` locally to change the state, it will end up overwritten by the props. One possible approach would be to call a method that the parent would give us (like `fetchSingleMasterAgent`), that would change the parents props, hence giving `getDerivedStateFromProps` new data to relay on. Not sure if it's 100% clear now, just ask if it's not :).

Answer (score 0):

Change attribute `field` to `name` in code:

```
<TextField
  className="mydevice2"
  error={errors.device2}
  id="device2"
  name="device2"
  onChange={this.onChange}
  placeholder="Number of IGR devices"
  type="text"
  value={device2 || ''}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but is not the problem. I did this before I asked the question here

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(
this.props./*any your prop or data fetched status from API call*/ === value &&
prevProps./*same prop name*/ !== value) {
    this.setState(
    {
            id: this.props.singleMasterAgent.id,
            fullname: this.props.singleMasterAgent.fullname,
            username: this.props.singleMasterAgent.username,
            address: this.props.singleMasterAgent.address,
            email: this.props.singleMasterAgent.email,
            phoneNumber: `${this.props.singleMasterAgent.phoneNumber}`,
            password: this.props.singleMasterAgent.password,
            device1: this.props.singleMasterAgent.device1,
            device2: this.props.singleMasterAgent.device2,
          }
    )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what do I use for the condition because my props is returning an object while the prevprops is returning an empty object